# Fusionauth ADFS integration issue

Tags: fusionauth

I'm evaluating the FusionAuth server locally on my windows machine and I'm trying to set up a identity provider to a adfs server. I have followed the steps as outlined in the [docs](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/identity-providers/samlv2/adfs).

After I login at the adfs I get a 405 error at the /samlv2/acs page.

I have enabled the debug flag on the provider. However no events show up in the System -> Event log page. Should I be able to see these events there?

Under logs catalogue I see a "fusionauth-search" file but no "fusionauth-app" log. Is the fusion-app log the correct place to debug this problem? What could be the reason why it is missing?

Thanks

Comment: If you're getting as `405` the IdP must be making a `GET` request to that endpoint instead of a `POST`? We only support the `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST` ACS binding. Are you using the SP metadata to configure ADFS or manually building the relying party configuration? If that all looks good, try changing the ACS endpoint to `/oauth2/callback` instead of `/samlv2/acs`, if that works then I may know what is happening.

Comment: This is a bug, it will be fixed shortly. You should be able to work around it by manually specifying the ACS endpoint and changing it to `/oauth2/callback`. Thanks!

Comment: Available in version 1.7.4

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug in FusionAuth version 1.7.3.

As a workaround, modify your relying party configuration to use `/oauth2/callback` instead of `/samlv2/acs`.

This has been resolved in version 1.7.4. Thanks!
https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/release-notes/

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I can confirm that it is working with version 1.7.4.